# How can I share a scope with a directive in another module without using "scope: false"?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 modules, `jsTag` and `mainApp`.  `mainApp` injects jsTag to use it's functionality

```
var jsTag = angular.module('jsTag')
angular.module('mainApp', ['jsTag']);
```

The jsTag module has a directive I'll call jsTagDirective

```
jsTag.directive('jsTagDirective', function(){
restrict: 'E',
scope: true,
controller: 'jsTagMainCtrl',
templateUrl: 'jsTag/source/Templates/js-tag.html'
```

The template of the above directive has an `input` tag inside of it, with an `ng-model` reference to `jsText`.  I want to be able to capture the value of this model in the controller of my `mainApp` module.  Changing scope to false does work - I can access `$scope.jsText` in the mainApp - but I understand this is bad practice.  I can't figure out how to get inherited scope or isolated scope to pass the value upwards, though.

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a perfect example why you should use isolated scope along with two-way binding. [Docs here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object)

JS

```
jsTag.directive('jsTagDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            jsText: '='
        },
        controller: 'jsTagMainCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'jsTag/source/Templates/js-tag.html'
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<js-tag-directive js-text="jsText"></js-tag-directive>
```

This will make the directive have its jsText property in sync with a parent scope, even creating the said property.